# geoFire .getLocation using Firebase and need an observe to monitor changes as they occur, Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am using GeoFire in Swift and am able to .setLocation for a user and .getLocation I can retrieve their location and it all works good, i can then create an annotation and also create a poly line to a destination.

What I would now like to do is to move the user location along the polyline as the user travels.

To do this I was wondering how can I setup a Firebase.observe to let me know when the user moves and the map will auto update

The code I use for getLocation (snippet)

```
func fetchTradeLocationTest() {
    guard let uid = tradeUser?.uid else { return }
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: DB_REF.child("tradelocation"))
    geoFire.getLocationForKey(uid) { (location, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("DEBUG: An error occurred getting the location for \"tradeLocation\": \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        } else if (location != nil) {
            print("DEBUG: location = \(location)")
        } else {
            print("DEBUG: GeoFire does not contain a location for \"tradeLocation\"")
        }
    }
}
```

Wonder if anyone can guide me on how to set it up as an observer such that i get updated position.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Part of the core functionality of GeoFire is to let your app know when something changes - which appears to be what you're asking about. You probably want key moved. Check out the [Documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#receiving-events-for-geo-queries) for some example code. If that's not what you're asking, please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

GeoFire adds the ability to [run geoqueries](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/#geo-queries) on Firebase, which means that you can find the keys that are in a certain geographic range and detect the data in it, and changes to that data.

In your specific use-case, you already know the key that you want to monitor. This mens you don't need a geoquery, but instead can use the [regular `observe` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_value_events) of the Realtime Database to monitor that specific key: